# Module update not detected

Tags: module, update

I've written the XML for the updateserver per the documentation, and tested that it is both valid and has a downloadurl that is functional.

I have tried to clear the cache and check for updates, but every time no updates for my plugin are returned. I've tried it on two different Joomla! installs on two different servers, both with module versions at least 1 below that of the update.

There's very little documentation on errors, and any help would be appreciated. I'm willing to dig into the update check code if I can be pointed towards its location.

```
<updates>
<update>
    <name>Module name</name>
    <description>Redacted Description</description>
    <element>mod_redacted</element>
    <type>module</type>
    <client>site</client>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <downloads>
        <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">http://redacted.url/updates/mod_redacted_101.zip</downloadurl>
    </downloads>
    <tags>
    <tag>stable</tag>
    </tags>
    <maintainer>Joseph B.</maintainer>
    <maintainerurl>redacted</maintainerurl>
    <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.1"/>
</update>
```

```
<updateservers>
    <server type="extension" name="Redacted Updates" priority="2">http://redacted.url/redacted.xml</server>
</updateservers>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full code from your update XML and the code in the `<updateservers>` tags in your module XML?

Comment: I have. I apologize for having to put redacted in so many places, but this is not something I can have publicly shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anybody who stumbles upon this in the future, the problem was caused by a mix of poor reading skills and awkward tag names.

`targetplatform` looks for that platform level and that level only. You can specify `targetplatform="3.[012345]`, but the running Joomla! version *must* fall within that range or the update won't be detected. This is, in my opinion, awkward wording, as most systems use *target* to specify which is the tested environment, not which is the required environment.